# OpenNMS installation fails with error, expected stable but got opennms-23, is it possible to go trought it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian-based, opennms

By following the Debian installation section at page https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-install/guide-install.html on a brand new Ubuntu 18 LTS I am getting an error after the last command, is any way to access a recent working repository rather than the broken version 23 ? 
Thanks in advance.

```
su root

cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opennms.list
deb https://debian.opennms.org stable main
deb-src https://debian.opennms.org stable main
EOF

wget -O - https://debian.opennms.org/OPENNMS-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -

apt update

apt -y install opennms
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, can you share that?

Comment: immediately after the wget I am getting:
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
after the apt update Iam getting a GPG error: https://debian.opennms.org stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 57801F6F5B9EFD43

Comment: Me too. I've raised it as a bug: https://issues.opennms.org/browse/NMS-10673

Comment: As an aside, [the `cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); you can pass a here document to `tee` directly.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this issue today using the same instruction page for Debian.  It appears that in the repository, `stable` is symlinked to the current stable version's directory, but [stable's release file](https://debian.opennms.org/dists/stable/Release) in the repository does not contain the word "stable" so apt complains.

I was able to work around the issue by editing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opennms.list, commenting out the "stable" line and replacing it with one explicitly naming the version:

```
#deb http://debian.opennms.org/ stable main
deb http://debian.opennms.org/ opennms-23 main
```

After that, the apt errors went away.  This has the side effect that you will need to edit the list any time a newer major version is released.